# Dynamically getting tags in post edit screen

Tags: plugin-development, metabox, tags

I am trying to dynamically get the post's tags as the user adds them while editting a post, but I have not found any hook related to that action.

I know I can make my own hooks, but the thing is that I can not edit the theme, so I can not make it that way (or I have not found a proper one)

The idea is to be able to get the tags as the user adds or deletes them, but I'm getting crazy with such a silly thing.

[image: WP_tags_metabox]

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to hook in when the post is saved, rather than as they are added. I doubt there is a hook for when they are added simply because that info is not saved until the entire post is saved.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is but a patch, but i followed WebElaine advise and hooked my function to the "save_post" hook.
As I wanted my plugin to be used while editing the post, I have added button to update the tags that actually saves the post.